# Real alternative to 1Password standalone

Tags: password-manager

1Password pushes people to create cloud accounts and pay subscription fees and it seems like they want to retire a standalone app eventually (although they don't want to admit it) ‒ i.e. you cannot buy Windows license anymore. So I am looking for an alternative.

My requirements are:

- free or one-time pay (can be for each platform separately)
- clients for Windows, Mac and iOS (Android is a plus, mostly for future readers, not me)
- Firefox add-on
- passwords stored locally, not on their server
- some kind of sync, OneDrive preferred

What I tried and didn't like:

- Dashlane, Intuitive Password, Keeper, LastPass ‒ all store passwords on their servers
- MSecure ‒ no browser add-ons

What I tried and kind of liked:

- Enpass ‒ it looks really great but it is India based company and they are [postponing security audit](https://discussion.enpass.io/index.php?/topic/404-security-audit/)
- KeePass ‒ I guess it can meet all requirements but requires a lot of work to set everything up. Although it is on my backup list

Any other recommendations? Did I miss something?

Comment: Not a qualified choice due to the periodic payment, not one-time, is Roboform. Works with Firefox, iOS, Windows, Mac, local password storage, sync, but not cloud based.

Comment: By using RoboForm Everywhere (the paid version) the passwords are accessible by web portal. Doesn't that mean that they need to store them?

Comment: I believe you may be correct in that respect. It's also possible that if the passwords are not synchronized they may not appear on the web portal. Clearly, RoboForm isn't going to be the correct answer for your requirements. I was disappointed when they moved to a subscription program.

Comment: If you don't want your passwords stored on a server, then where do you them synchronized to?

Comment: OneDrive, Dropbox etc. I prefer to use them rather then trusting some random company and for OneDrive it's just a binary file. Also, storing passwords on someone's server usually means paying for subscription but I already pay for OneDrive.

Comment: While there is a password manager called [KeyPass](https://www.dobysoft.com/products/keypass/), the much more well-known product is [**KeePass**](https://keepass.info/).